# Не работает DNS в ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ethernet

Проблема только с одним компом в сети. Ping по ip адресу идёт, по имени нет. ДНС в настройках карты 192.168.1.1, пробовал устанавливать публичные яндекса, результат тот же.

```
ping ya.ru
ping: unknown host ya.ru

ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:f2:16:bb:e4  
          inet addr:192.168.1.210  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:f2ff:fe16:bbe4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23456 errors:0 dropped:60 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6018 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2072033 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:544421 (544.4 KB)
```

Comment: Настройки автоматические (dhcp) или ручные? DNS-сервера в /etc/resolv.conf есть/нету? Используется ли какой-нибудь NetworkManager?

Comment: Через графическую утилиту настроил статический ip, на роутере также сделал связь мак-Ip в  /etc/resolv.conf  nameserver 127.0.0.1

Comment: @andreymal в файле /etc/resolv.conf установил dns заработало. Как теперь сделать так чтобы при перезапуске не затирались настройки файла?

Comment: По идее графическая утилита должна позволять проставить dns и самостоятельно дописывать /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @andreymal спасибо решил проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf.head
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Так после перезагрузки настройки не сбрасываются

Comment: По идее должно быть написано `nameserver 8.8.8.8` на одной строке и `nameserver 8.8.4.4` на другой строке